# PSP with partial refund option after some time

Tags: paypal, laravel-5, stripe-payments, recurly

I am going to build a web site that will have few products, and a shopping cart. Every product will have an expiry or end time. Customers will buy any of the product(s) and after the product is expired, I need to gave back a discount of few bucks to all the customers(Partial Refund.)
Now the question is which PSP(Payment service provider) I could use for this purpose.? 
I have came across Stripe (https://stripe.com/). Its a very good PSP. but they require me to store all the product information on their API and calculate prices on their own (which I dont want). All I need is to have the option of order and refund back after sometime.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Stripe does not *require* you to store product information -- you can simply [create one-off charges](https://stripe.com/docs/charges) for the amount you want.

Once a charge has been created successfully, you can [refund it](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_refund), either fully or partially (by providing an [`amount`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_refund-amount) parameter in the refund creation request.)